# How can I remove foreign word from Bengali text in python

Tags: python, text, nlp, text-processing

I have a text data file which consist of raw bangla text data with so much foreign words
I want to remove all foreign words from Bengali raw text.

input:

```
দেশের রাজনীতি দিনকে দিন পচে যাচ্ছে। पैरेनकाइमा कोशिकाएं . what a shame. সুস্থ থাকা দায়।
```

Output:

```
দেশের রাজনীতি দিনকে দিন পচে যাচ্ছে। সুস্থ থাকা দায়।
```

Any suggestion or idea will help me a lot.

thanks in advance.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what *Christian Sloper* mentioned in the comments. Apparently the correct ord range is 2432 to 2559 so something like this seems to work:

```
import re

a = "দেশের রাজনীতি দিনকে দিন পচে যাচ্ছে। पैरेनकाइमा कोशिकाएं . what a shame. সুস্থ থাকা দায়।"

a = "".join(i for i in a if i in [".","।"] or 2432 <= ord(i) <= 2559 or ord(i)== 32)
re.sub(' +', ' ', a)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. It's working but it also removing punctuation (।) . is there a way to skip punctuations?

Comment: @SagorSarker what exactly do you mean by punctuation? Just the one character (।)? If so then it's done.

Comment: Hi, In output it removes (.) and (।) . But I got the idea here. thanks and regards

Answer (score 2):

Use `re` with `split()` function to remove multiple whilespaces.

```
import re

a = "দেশের রাজনীতি দিনকে দিন পচে যাচ্ছে। पैरेनकाइमा कोशिकाएं . what a shame. সুস্থ থাকা দায়।"

a = "".join(i for i in a if i in ["।"] or 2432 <= ord(i) <= 2559 or ord(i)== 32)
a=" ".join(a.split())
print(a)
```

**Outupt:**

```
দেশের রাজনীতি দিনকে দিন পচে যাচ্ছে। সুস্থ থাকা দায়।
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ord` to filter out "western characters and punctuation" (sorry for lack of better word), and `re` to remove multiple spaces.

```
import re

a = "দেশের রাজনীতি দিনকে দিন পচে যাচ্ছে। पैरेनकाइमा कोशिकाएं . what a shame. সুস্থ থাকা দায়।"

a = "".join(i for i in a if ord(i) > ord('z') or ord(i)== 32)
re.sub(' +', ' ', a)
```

returns:

```
'দেশের রাজনীতি দিনকে দিন পচে যাচ্ছে। पैरेनकाइमा कोशिकाएं সুস্থ থাকা দায়।'
```

Comment: Hi @ChristianSloper thank you so much for quick response. But it still contains hindi text inside bangla. `पैरेनकाइमा कोशिकाएं`. I am finding a solution that can remove any foreign word from Bangla text. thanks and regards

Comment: sorry. I cannot tell what is what, but i assume that they have separate ord-ranges, so you can just use a similar filter based on that.  try to figure out what is first and last bangla ord-value and filter on that.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will follow your suggestions. regards